# Meteor method to start game object

Tags: javascript, meteor

I would like to create multiple game instances.

Currently, on the client side a game template is rendered

```
Template.game.rendered = function () {

    graph = new Graph("#graph", nodes);

};

   // 

function Graph(selector, nodes) { //code here };
```

This give me a single game instance. Now I would like to create more game instances, hosted in a 'lobby'.

For this I have a collection.lobby.

```
id, 
host, 
players,
status,
invitedplayers,
url
```

This functionality works: I can set the collection values and retrieve them under the assigned url.

Now I need to create a new game instance with this.

I think that I need a Meteor.method that 'renders' a new game container at the specified url. Is this correct ?
How do I have to combine these elements ?

There is enough sample code on github, but everyone does this a little different, so that I have not been able to analyze and understand how to do it.

The answer seem so be here [Loading templates with iron router](http://www.jonahnisenson.com/loading-templates-with-iron-router-in-meteor/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ed Die,

If you take a look through the [full api documentation](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/meteor_call) for Meteor, and search for the keyword "chat", you'll find examples of chat-room instances being created, which seems very similar to what you're trying to accomplish.

You may or may not need to have a unique url routed, for example www.mygame.com/game/MONGO_ID_HERE or a different generated ID.

The approach could be that each game url or session id get's stored into the database, that game's session data get's stored into that document, and when someone is playing the game, they get assigned that session's id until the game is over.

I hope this helps.

Comment: I have the players, lobbyid and url stored, but there is no actual rendering of my game template.  I do not understand how I can trigger a new game to be rendered.

Comment: 1. Does your game template ever get rendered? 
2. Are you using any routing package?

Comment: the template gets rendered on page load. It is set inside $("#gamecontainer").hide, then shown on button click. iron:router; I have the values ( 'players' ) from the lobby collection at the proper url, just no rendered game